# Identify this game - strange yellow plastic piece

Tags: identify-this-game

We recently purchased the game Cootie second hand (Good Will style), and inside the box we found a piece that we are pretty sure doesn't belong. It's a curved plastic yellow piece that we think came from a different game and was included for some reason in this box.

[image: yellow piece]
[image: end]
[image: side view]

There is writing on the end: BART INDUSTRIES INC and some other text that I can't make out.

So does this come from another game? Or is it something else entirely?

**Edit**
Dimensions are approx. 2.5" tall, with about a 1" diameter base (the first photo below is slightly misleading due to the hidden base on the object and the space at the end of the ruler)

[image: measurement a]
[image: measurement b]

Comment: That looks familiar, I think it's the tail or horn from a toy animal. Can you tell us its size?

Comment: Dimensions added

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It appears to be the tail piece from "Zoo it yourself" Tupperware animal toys.

[https://www.amazon.com/Tupperware-Tuppertoys-Zoo-It-Yourself-5-piece-ELEPHANT/dp/B00FN34D34](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FN34D34)

[image: Promo Photo]

You can see the individual pieces here:
[image: Photo of Pieces]

Comment: Nice Find! I added another photo off of Google Image search of "tupperware Tupper toys"